# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Bose QuietComfort 35 ii

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

I just installed Ubuntu this week and I have a pair of Bose QuietComfort 35 II. The only issue I'm experiencing is when choosing High Fidelity (A2DP Sink). The input device automatically switches to Internal Microphone, which is a problem nowadays with all the meetings.

Is there someone experiencing this or something I can do?

Comment: I have issues with the mic as well, still haven't found a solution for this. You can look at similar cases here: https://community.bose.com/t5/Around-On-Ear-Headphones/qc35-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04/td-p/300415 but no real help, if you found something I would love to hear...

Answer (score 4):

This currently isn't possible; the A2DP profile only allows playing audio, not recording, and the HSP profile that allows for recording has very low playback quality.  You can only pick one, which means you have to choose between high-quality playback or low-quality playback & recording.

The good news is that the current release candidate for PulseAudio 15 includes support for higher-quality codecs with the HFP profile, and so you *should* be able to get high-quality playback and recording at the same time with it.  More details are here:
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2021-May/032082.html

If you're not comfortable building & installing PulseAudio from source, hopefully PA 15 will make its way into Ubuntu by either 21.10 or 22.04.